# Not able to resolve linker error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, artoolkit

I have included ARToolkit in app for Multiple Marker Detection. I am able to integrate "Hiro" pattern detection but for Multiple Marker Detection Using "App2" (in example), getting following linker errors. Anybody has idea what could be issue?[image]

Comment: You probably missed to add those referenced files in build phase compile resource section.

Comment: i have added Eden library also VEObjectOBJ.h/.m both files are there

Answer (score 0):

Negligence to go into details and copy/paste made me miss some files adding to project. Now its working fine. Thank you.

Comment: what files did you add?